# Next-Auth getSession is returning null in my middleware.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware, next.js13, next-auth

Basically, I am trying to create middleware in my next js project, I have a fully functional login system using next auth, and now I want to redirect users to different dashboard pages based on their role after logging in. For example, if the user role is admin then the user should be redirected to the /admin page and if the user role is donor then the user should be redirected to the /donor page and I want to do it using middleware.js,

However, I am unable to get the session to extract the user role present in the session. It returns a null value.
but I can get the session in normal react components like the one below

```
const {data: session} = useSession()
const role = session?.user?.role
```

But I am unable to get the session using getSession() in the middleware.js 
Note: useSession() does not work for middleware

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/admin/:path*", "/donor/:path*"],
};

// Define the paths for different roles
const roleRedirects = {
  admin: "/admin",
  donor: "/donor",
};

export async function middleware(request) {
  const session = await getSession({request});
  const role = session?.user?.role;

  console.log(session); // getting null value

  if (session && role && roleRedirects[role]) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(roleRedirects[role]);
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

for better understanding I have added my [...nextauth].js code also

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { connectDB } from "@/backend/utils/dbConnect";
import prisma from "@/prisma/prismaClient";

export const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {},

      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { identifier, password } = credentials;

        try {
          await connectDB();
          const user = await prisma.users.findFirst({
            where: {
              OR: [{ email: identifier }, { phone: identifier }],
            },
          });

          if (user !== null) {
            const passwordMatching = await bcrypt.compare(
              password,
              user.password
            );

            if (passwordMatching !== false) {
              return user;
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          return {
            apiMessage: {
              errorMsg: "Unexpected Error occurred ",
              error: error,
            },
          };
        }
      },
    }),
  ],

  //   session
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60, // Set the session max age 7 days
    expires: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // set the session expiration time 30 days
  },

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      user && (token.user = user);
      return token;
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.id = token.user.id;
      session.user.role = token.user.role;
      delete session?.user?.email;
      delete session?.user?.phone;
      delete session?.user?.password;
      return session;
    },
  },

  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },

  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Comment: Same issue I am facing right now. session returning null. Does anyone have a solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

NextAuth's `getSession()` [runs on the server](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getsession), not the client side. The middleware also runs on the clients side.

> NextAuth.js provides a getSession() helper which should be called
> client side only to return the current active session.

You could [use cookies](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware) to pass what you need to access.